# Convert more than 2 channels audio to mono

Tags: c#, mp3, wav, channel, naudio

I am using the next code for converting stereo to mono:

```cs
using (var waveFileReader = new WaveFileReader(sourceStream))
{
    var outFormat = new WaveFormat(waveFileReader.WaveFormat.SampleRate, 1);
    using (var resampler = new MediaFoundationResampler(waveFileReader, outFormat))
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream(stream, resampler);

        var format = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(waveFileReader.WaveFormat.SampleRate, 1);
        var writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(stream, format, 32);

        writer.Flush();
        byte[] channelBytes = stream.ToArray();
        writer.Dispose();

        File.WriteAllBytes(outputFile, channelBytes);
    }
}
```

I am wondering if it is possible to convert more than 2 channels (I have 8 channels audio) audio to mono audio?

Comment: Don't misuse tags. The mono tag is for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems like I found an answer to my question:

```
using (var waveFileReader = new WaveFileReader(sourceFile))
{
    var outFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);
    using (var resampler = new MediaFoundationResampler(waveFileReader, outFormat))
    {
        VolumeWaveProvider16 vol = new VolumeWaveProvider16(resampler)
        {
            Volume = 2f
        };
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream(stream, vol);

        var format = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(outFormat.SampleRate, 1);
        var writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(stream, format, 32);

        writer.Flush();
        byte[] channelBytes = stream.ToArray();
        writer.Dispose();

        File.WriteAllBytes(outputFile, channelBytes);
    }
}
```